# Im having trouble using PHP to calculate the depreciation of an asset without a database (mainly with where to define the variables)

Tags: php

The below is the page where the user will enter their info and submit it to the PHP program

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <head>
        
    <title>Depreciation Calculator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Enter Your info</h1>
        <form action="deprecalc.php" method="post">
        <div id="data">
       
            
        <label>Item name</label>
        <input type="text" name="item_name"/>
                
        <label>Purchase price</label>
        <input type="text" name="purchase_price"/>
            </br>
        <label>No. of years</label>
        <input type="text" name="no_of_years"/>
            </br>
        <label>Salvage value</label>
        <input type="text" name="salvage_value"/>
            </br>        
        </div>
            <div id="buttons">
        <label>&nbsp</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate"></br>
            </div>    
        </form>
    </div>    
    
    </body>

</html>
```

And this is the page the data is being submitted to. My issue is where to define the variables needed to use this formula: Depreciation = (Purchase Price – Remaining Value) / Useful Life.

```
    <?php
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $purchase_price = $_POST['purchase_price'];
    $no_of_years = $_POST['no_of_years'];
    $salvage_value = $_POST['salvage_value'];
    $remaining_value = $purchase_price - $depreciation; 
    $depreciation = ($purchase_price - $remaining_value) / $no_of_years;
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Depreciation Calculator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
    
    <style>
    #values {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #values td, #values th {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    #values tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
    
    #values tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
    
    #values th {
      padding-top: 12px;
      padding-bottom: 12px;
      text-align: left;
      background-color: navy;
      color: white;
    }
    </style>
    
    <body>
    
        <h2>Item: <?php echo $item_name;?></h2></br>
        <h2>Cost: <?php echo $purchase_price;?></h2></br>
        
    <table id="values">
      <tr>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Depreciation to date</th>
        <th>Remaining value</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <?php
            $i=1;
            
            while ($i <= $no_of_years){
                echo "<td>" . $i++ . "</td>";
            }
        
            ?>
        <?php
            
            while ($remaining_value >= 0){
                echo "<td>" . $depreciation . "</td>";
            }
            
            ?>
       <?php
          
            
            while ($depreciation <= $purchase_price){
                echo "<td>" . $remaining_value . "</td>";
            }
           
            ?>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    </body>
    </html>
    
       
    </div>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm supposed to display it in a table format with the table heads being year, depreciation to data, and remaining value. When I run the above code, it simply outputs the year 1-5, followed by a never ending string of 0's, which I know means that it's stuck in a loop, and I've tried putting an endwhile at the end of each loop, but I then get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "endwhile", expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\deprecalc.php on line 68

Comment: There's no `endwhile` in the code you posted.

Comment: Which line is line 68?

Comment: `while ($depreciation <= $purchase_price)` you never update either variable in the loop, so it's an infinite loop.

Comment: I removed the endwhile because that's the only way I've gotten it to do anything so far. Line 68 is where the first endwhile was (right under the closing bracket in the first while loop).

Comment: `while ($remaining_value >= 0)` you never update `$remaining_value` in the loop, so that's also an infinite loop.

Comment: Oh, that's where I went wrong. I'm just confused as to how/where to define those variables so that they are updated and don't throw an error.

Comment: You should just have a single loop that creates each row of the table. Within the loop you update `$i`, `$remaining_value`, and `$depreciation`, and print each of them in the appropriate `<td>` of that row.

Comment: by they way if I use your code as it is, I see an issue here as well
$remaining_value = $purchase_price - $depreciation; 
 $depreciation = ($purchase_price - $remaining_value) / $no_of_years;
You are using $depreciation before defining it! Unless I am missing some piece of code, this will give you an error

Comment: Yeah, I've tried defining depreciation before using it, and I haven't been able to figure out a way to accomplish that without using $remainingvalue before defining it instead. That's what my issue is; I can't wrap my head around the logic part of this.